# How to add "See all" button in table view cell

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, uitableview

How to add "See all >" button right of the title in `UITableViewCell` like in app store app?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJ5tX.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the button (and the header title) to a custom `UIView` and add that as a table header (using `-[UITableView 
tableHeaderView]`

Answer (score 0):

Something like that :

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
[button setTitle:@"See all"];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:button];
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply drag a `UIButton` in your custom UITableViewCell. Make that `UIButton` appearance style to custom and write your content text "See All>". Make a link of button property in the `CustomCell`.h file and add a targetSelector to the button in `cellForRowAtIndexPathMethod` of `UITableView` delegate method. For ex-

```
[seeAllBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(seeAllAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Don't forget to implement this method in the `owner` controller of your `UITableView`.